# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred for Network Layer

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am trying to create a Generic Network layer and I have created a `ServiceHelperClass`.

```
class ServiceHelper: NSObject {


static let sharedInstance = ServiceHelper() 

func sendRequest<T: Decodable,Q: Encodable>(path: String, encodingData: Q, completion: @escaping(T?, Error?) -> Void)
{
    guard let url = URL(string: Constants.TEST_URL + path) else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    do {

        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(encodingData)

        request.httpBody = jsonBody

    } catch { fatalError("JSON Body Failed")}

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response, err) in

        if let response = response {

            print(response)

        }

        if let err = err {

            print("Failed to fetch data:", err.localizedDescription, "Error Description\(err)")

            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as Any)

            let dataReceived = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

            completion(dataReceived,nil)

        } catch let jsonErr {

            print("Failed to serialize json:", jsonErr, jsonErr.localizedDescription)

            completion( nil,jsonErr)
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}

}
```

So, now when I am calling it in my `ViewModel`, I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

I am calling it like this:

```
    func initFetching(onCompletion: @escaping(WinningViewModel?, Error?)-> Void)
    {

    let encoded = WinEncodable(api_token: Constants.USER_INFO["api_token"].stringValue, contest_id: Constants.CONTESTID)

    ServiceHelper.sharedInstance.sendRequest(path: "contest-winner-option",encodingData: encoded) { (decoded, error) in

        if let error = error
        {
            print(error)

            return
        }

        else
        {
            print(decoded)
        }

    }
    }
```

How to resolve this error? Why am I getting this error? Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler doesn't know about your `T` (output decodable type)

So you need to provide  output type i.e Decodable object type just like below example

not sure but you're is `WinningViewModel`

```
ServiceHelper.sharedInstance.sendRequest(path: "contest-winner-option",encodingData: encoded) { (response: WinningViewModel?, error) in
   if let error = error {
       print(error)
       return
     } else {
        print(decoded)
     }    
}
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: i guess this would work but it's against the generic principles

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't think there is rules violation for generic type. If you could explain so that I can make change in my answer

Comment: explicitly doing `: WinningViewModel?`  is against generics the called method should infer it with it's own

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry but  I think you have confusion with concepts. Your point is absolutely correct for the `ServiceHelper` class where I can not directly use `: WinningViewModel?` then it is no more generic. But When I call the method `sendRequest` compiler does need to know what is `T` and what is `Q` . so for `Q` we have passed `encoded` but for `T` we need to provide the output type and there is not other way to do this. until you create `initFetching` method generic let's say with type `X`  and provide  `:X?` but providing type is very much required

Comment: I have added `type` in the parameter as `type: T.Type`. It solved the issue.

Comment: @Rob Don't need to do that You can resolve `T` at runtime using given solution. This doesn't make sense that you pass the Type T

Comment: I am unable to see that in your solution, can you please re-explain?

Comment: @Rob I have already explained in comment above (see the longest) let me know if you still have a confusion

Answer (score 0):

In your exemple the compiler has no way to know what type decoded is.

A solution is to add the type of decoded as a parameter:

```
func sendRequest<T: Decodable,Q: Encodable>(path: String, encodingData: Q, decodedType: T.Type, completion: @escaping(T?, Error?) -> Void)
```

And when you call it use WinningViewModel.self as argument.

At the same time make sure that WinningViewModel conforms to Decodable to match T requirements.

Regards,

Comment: Yes, I have just done that and I am testing it out now.

Comment: you can also write it as a method inside the class , so it's call will be inferred with `encoded....` without sending the type as a parameter